# Increment using awk

Tags: awk

Using awk how can I increment a number going down a line?

example:

```
1.  LastName, FirstName
2.  LastName, FirstName
```

I was thinking something such as awk '{print '/\d/'}'

Comment: Do you just want the `NR` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file content is formatted like that:

```
LastName, FirstName
LastName, FirstName
```

and you want to get the following:

```
1.  LastName, FirstName
2.  LastName, FirstName
```

You can acheive it with the following `awk` command:

```
awk '{print NR". "$0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a sequence of lines (conveniently we have `seq` for a demo):

```
$ seq 1 3
1
2
3
```

With awk, just use `NR` to print the line number of each line of the file or sequence:

```
$ seq 1 3 | awk '{print NR". "$1}'    
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a command for this: `nl`  You can add formatting as well

```
$ nl -s". " file
```